# Resetear Arreglo Double Bidimensional c#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un dibujo y quería hacer unas funciones que se realizaran pero sin que afecten a los valores originales

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    clear();
    // Aux
    aux1 = caseG;
    aux2 = glass1;
    aux3 = glass2;
    // Trasnlations
    translation(ref caseG, Convert.ToDouble(trans1.Text), Convert.ToDouble(trans2.Text));
    translation(ref glass1, Convert.ToDouble(trans1.Text), Convert.ToDouble(trans2.Text));
    translation(ref glass2, Convert.ToDouble(trans1.Text), Convert.ToDouble(trans2.Text));
    // Draws
    draw(caseG, new SolidBrush(Color.Black));
    draw(glass1, new SolidBrush(Color.White));
    draw(glass2, new SolidBrush(Color.White));
    // Return
    caseG = aux1;
    glass1 = aux2;
    glass2 = aux3;
}
```

Como variables iniciales en la clase puse

```
double[,] caseG, glass1, glass2, aux1, aux2, aux3;
```

Ósea que todos serían básicamente lo mismo

La función de translación hace una referencia para que modifique el valor y lo regrese, solo hace una suma que hay en unos texbox

Pero al momento de hacer click, sigue sumando los valores en vez de dejarlo  en lo mismo, lo cual debería hacer :c

Comment: Pero estas pisando los valores al final del metodo del boton click. No Entiendo que te falla

Comment: No lo sé @RamiroBarone :c Los copio al inicio y luego los regreso, no sé dónde está el error

Comment: Creo que ya vi porque @RamiroBarone en C# no copia realmente, creo que tengo que clonarlo

Comment: Pero no encuento como clonar un double[,] :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tus variables son arrays, por tanto mantienen la referencia entre ellas, si quieres clonarlas y quitar las referencias prueba con:

```
aux1 = caseG.Clone() as double[,];
aux2 = glass1.Clone() as double[,];
aux3 = glass2.Clone() as double[,];
```